# PUSH data to stack and POP and print in loop(emu8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

this is my program. I'm using "emu8086". It supposed to take 5 characters from user and push them to stack and then pop and print them. E.g. input 12345, output 54321. This code works but after printing the data's in the stack some other characters also gets printed. Whats wrong here?

```
.data

.code

main proc    

    mov cx, 5
    l1:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h   
    mov ax, ax
    push ax
    loop l1

    l2:
    pop cx
    mov dx, cx
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    loop l2

endp
end main
```

Output...
http://s16.postimg.org/5zr9gmfvl/Untitled111.png

Comment: Think about what `cx` becomes after `pop cx`.

Comment: a little context please!

Comment: `cx` is the counter for `loop`. You have a double-use of that register for the character to print as well.

Comment: doesn't work. if i use POP DX still the same output.

Comment: You also have to initialize the counter again for the output, like you do for the input.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Answer the question so that i can choose your answer. As you can see i'm new at SO. You can give my question a vote up to help me if you want! :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the stack.
Set si to the end of the string, set the direction-reversing-flag using STD.
Now, every lodsb or lodsw will decrease SI instead of increasing it. Don't forget to clear  the direction-reversing-flag using CLD.

Answer (score 0):

Do this after `l1:`  loop ends.  `pop1` is your `l2:`

```
    mov cx,5

pop1:
    pop dx
    ;mov dx, cx
    mov ah, 2

    int 21h
    loop pop1
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included the explanation of *why* this fixes the problem (like the comments under the question).